# Screenshot of popover not coming clear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am developing an ios app, in which i need to take a screenshot of image but i am not able to take the correct screenshot of popovers on screen.
Here is my actual image

[image]

and after taking screenshot I am getting following image

[image]

My code for capturing image is as follows

```
    UIWindow *topWindow = nil;

    topWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];

    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
    if(view == nil){
        size =  [[topWindow.rootViewController view] bounds].size;
    }else{
        size =  [view bounds].size;
    }

    if([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0f){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,2.0f);
    }else{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    }

    if(view == nil){
        // Put everything in the current view into the screenshot
        [[[[topWindow subviews] objectAtIndex:0] layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        //Code for capturing popover
        [[[topWindow subviews].lastObject layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        }
    }else{
        // Put everything in the current view into the screenshot
        [[view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }

    // Save the current image context info into a UIImage
    UIImage *imageToBeEdited = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Execute that routine from the main thread.

Comment: Hmm.. It's ridiculous then. I suspected drawing consistency issues. Your screen capture shows unfinished, work in progress images.

Comment: I have the same issue... Did you solve your problem Sunil??

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change :

```
if(view == nil)
{
   size =  [[topWindow.rootViewController view] bounds].size;
}else{
   size =  [view bounds].size;
}
```

to :

```
if(view == nil)
{
    size =  [[topWindow.rootViewController view] bounds].size;
}else{
    size =  view.frame.size;
}
```